# Can multiple EC2 (non-terminated) apply one AWS Reserved Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am going to buy one AWS Reserved Instance and launch several EC2 instances. But these EC2 instances would not be running across time range. For example, `instance 1` will be running from `00:00 to 11:59` and then be stopped. `instance 2` will be running from `12:00` to `24:59` and then be stopped.

I'd like to know if only one Reserved Instance can apply to this two instances?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short : Yes

Long: Yes, the same Reserved Instance (RI) would apply to both the instances because RI is just a billing concept. It is not specifically associated with any instance.  The RI is automatically associated with any **running** instance. The instance chosen is such that your bill is the lowest.

So if you buy say 2 RIs and you run 4 instances at a time which match the RI criteria (instance-type, tenancy, region/availability zone and platform), the RI discount is automatically applied to any 2 of them.

Similarily, if you have 1 RI and 2 instances which match the criteria (the 4 attributes mentioned above) but only one instance is in **running** state at a time (others are in **stopped** state, not terminated) then yes, the RI discount will apply to both of them.

Just make sure that both instances are not running at the same time & both match the RI attributes.

**Edit 1**

> AWS Billing automatically applies your RI’s discounted rate when attributes of EC2 instance usage match attributes of an **active** RI.

Refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/#How_do_RIs_Work?) link. If you need further clarification/confirmation, you could contact AWS Customer Support by raising an **Account & Billing Support** case from your AWS Support center. You do not need to buy a support plan to raise billing cases & RIs are just a billing concept.

Comment: Thank you @agent420, could you please share references about this informations?

Comment: Edited the response. There are no public-facing docs with detailed examples/clarifications, but I have tested this on my account. If you need further confirmation, you could contact Billing Support.  Basic Support plan (free) is sufficient for that.